# Sum and difference of independent binomial random variables

Tags: probability, independence, binomial-distribution

Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are i.i.d. Binomial random variable where $X_1, X_2 \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n, 1/2)$. What can we say about the random variables $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 - X_2$?

I know they are *not* independent because only [independent Gaussian random variables have independent sums and differences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4089604/the-sum-and-difference-of-two-independent-random-variables-is-independent), but could they be "close to" independent? In particular, does there exist independent Binomial random variables $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ such that $Y_1 = X_1 + X_2 + O(1)$ and $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2 + O(1)$ (if we approximate Binomials with Gaussians then the error would be $O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$ but maybe a better bound is possible)?

Comment: $Y_1=X_1+X_2$ has a binomial distribution $\mathrm{Bin}(2n, 1/2)$.  $Y_2=X_1-X_2$ does not (it has an expectation of $0$) but $Y_2+n \sim  \mathrm{Bin}(2n, 1/2)$ too.  They have zero covariance, but are not "close" to independent:  for example $Y_2=n \implies Y_1 =n$ and $Y_1 =0  \implies Y_2 =0$

Comment: They are "close" to independent in the sense that $\tilde{X}_i=X_i-\frac{n}{2}$ can be interpreted as a random walk on the rotated and scaled grid (move $(\pm 1,\pm1)$ with probability 1/4 each) and look at the result after $n$ step, but $\sqrt{n}$ is the correct error term you can hope for.

Comment: @Henry, do you mean $Y_2 = 2n \implies Y_1 = 2n$? I agree that these implications mean the variables are not independent, but since these are low probability events, the hope was that they don't matter in the grand scheme of things...

Comment: @user10354138, thanks I was afraid that was going to be the case... Careful calculation of $\mathbb{P}[X_1 - X_2 = t]$ can be shown to be _exactly_ equal to an appropriately scaled standard Gaussian up to $O(1/n)$ error, but I guess that's not the case more generally

Comment: @XinYuanLi $Y_2=X_1-X_2$ can only take values from $-n$ to $n$ and if it is $n$ then $X_1=n$ and $X_2 =0$ and so $Y_1=X_1+X_2=n+0=n$. As for "the grand scheme of things", it depends on what you want to use independence for: zero covariance is fine, but some other issues are not.

Comment: @Henry, OK makes sense (I thought you had defined $Y_2 = X_1 - X_2 + n$). I am using the above in a condition probability. In particular I have variables $T_1 = X_3 + X_1 + X_2$ and $T_2 = X_1 - X_2$ and I want to compute $\mathbb{P}[T_1 = t_1 \land T_2 = t_2]$. By conditioning I have $\mathbb{P}[T_1 = t_1 \land T_2 = t_2] = \mathbb{P}[T_1 = t_1 | T_2 = t_2]\mathbb{P}[T_2 = t_2]$ which would be a lot easier to calculate if $T_1$ and $T_2$ (and therefore $X_1 + X_2$ and $X_1 - X_2$ were independent)